# DotNet command exiting with error code when building ActorService

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, actor

Im getting this error when building a ServiceActor in my project.

> Error MSB3073 The command "dotnet "obj\FabActUtilTemp\FabActUtil.dll"
>   /spp:"PackageRoot" /t:manifest /sp:
>   /in:"bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\win7-x64\.dll"
>   /arp:"D:\Projects\ECommerce\UserActor\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\win7-x64\"
>   " exited with code -1.

It came out of nowhere as the only thing i have been changing is some code.

I know now how to fix the error but ill refraise the question to ask why this is happening.

I have two projects
A) ActorService
B) ClassLibrary

Project A has a dependency to project B. Project B has a dependency to Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors (the latest version).

If project A also has a dependency to Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors i get the mentioned error. If i remove then the error dissapears and Project a gets the dependency to Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors through project A.

This did not happen before i upgraded the Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors to the latest version. What is happening?

Comment: try running the build with verbose output, to see what's failing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/obtaining-build-logs-with-msbuild?view=vs-2019

Comment: Ive tried this now and ive updated the OP. Thanks!

Comment: is project b a netstandard library? do both projects (a and b) target the exact same version of SF Actors?